# Root locus for an open loop transfer function?

Tags: control, transfer-function, matlab, pole-zeroplot, root-locus

The function, `rlocus()`, in MATLAB is used for *closed* loop system roots for variation in gain K. However, I am curious if there is a similar function for variation in parameter of *open* loop function. I have tried using the `pzmap()`  function and iterating to vary RL & IL. Unfortunately, it doesn't plot enough points on the graph. Are there any functions that will allow me to plot an open loop transfer function? I am trying to plot the transfer function below:

\$ T(s)= \frac{(RL+sIL)(3s^3+12s^2+12s+4)}{8s^4IL+s^3(28IL+8RL+3)+4s^2(7IL+7RL+3)+4s(2IL+7RL+3)+8RL+4}\$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you considered utilizing the `tf()` function and then doing `rlocus()`? For instance, let's call your transfer function above \$T(s)\$... so `t=tf(your transfer function)` and then `rlocus(t)`.

Comment: The input to the root locus procedure is the open-loop TF. This is because the RL starts at the open-loop poles and ends at the open-loop zeros. The RL determines closed-loop performance from the open-loop TF, so your question is meaningless.

Comment: Root locus is a plot of the *closed-loop* poles as the feedback gain changes. Poles of an *open-loop* system do not change position with *open-loop* gain. To say "pzmap doesn't plot enough points", or "root locus for open loop" are an indication of theoretical misconception.

Comment: @VicenteCunha the definition of Root locus you've stated it is incorrect. The thing  you've stated it one of many root locus's cases but the common one.

Comment: @CroCo I'd be happy to delete my comment if you point out where I'm wrong. From the matlab documentation: "The root locus gives the closed-loop pole trajectories as a function of the feedback gain k (assuming negative feedback). Root loci are used to study the effects of varying feedback gains on closed-loop pole locations.". I understand possible variations of use for control design, but the same definition still fits for an augmented system.

Comment: @VicenteCunha, the matlab documentation talks about the actual implementation of their function `rlocus` which is the common case but it is not the definition of root locus from control systems' perspective. The method is a graphical representation for determining all locations of system's poles if we vary one parameter. This parameter could be the gain, a pole, a zero, etc. The gain is the common case.

Comment: @VicenteCunha, you can find an example for varying a pole in control systems engineering by nise. The gain case is common because it is associated with controller design such as P, PI, PD, PID controllers.

Comment: @Croco Checked the book mentioned, indeed there is an example of root locus plotted with respect to pole variation. However, it does so by creating an equivalent system in which the parameter is now a gain. My comment remains correct in that all root locus plot rules are defined for variations in gain, and variations in parameters other than gain are tackled by rewriting the system, like the example. I will however concede that new plot rules can be formulated for variations of other parameters, expanding the concept of "root locus". But do you think this is what the questioner is looking for?

Comment: I misstated in my question and i am editing it now. i wanted to study the effect of varying IL and RL on system stability like rlocus but for an open loop transfer function varying IL and RL but the only way for that is doing a sweep but matlab wouldn't handle that amount of iteration so what i came up with is iterating on the above transfer function in a language that can handle the large number of iterations and solve for roots and either plot using library within the same language or export to matlab and draw using pzmap.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the semantics of "root locus," you can certainly plot the roots of a polynomial as its coefficients change.  The following script plots the set of poles of your system as \$RL\$ varies from 0 to 10000 with \$IL\$ fixed at 1:

```
IL = 1;
RLvec = linspace(0,10e3,1e5);
rts = zeros(1e5,4);
for k = 1:length(RLvec);
  RL = RLvec(k);
  D = [8*IL, 28*IL+8*RL+3, 4*(7*IL+7*RL+3), 4*(2*IL+7*RL+3), 8*RL+4];
  r = roots(D);
  rts(k,:) = r';
end;
figure
hold on;
for b = 1:4;
  plot(real(rts(:,b)),imag(rts(:,b)));
end;
xlim([-5,0]); grid on;
```

It executes for me in under 5 seconds.

Admittedly, it does not show how the roots move as *both* parameters change, but that task is complicated by having a two-dimensional domain and a two-(real)-dimensional range.

Comment: In case the roots don't come out 'sorted', the connecting lines may vary wildly. I couldn't find documentation that says that the roots returned will be in any particular order. [https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/405680-order-of-roots-obtained-from-function-roots]

Comment: My solution to that problem would be to omit the "lines" Matlab interpolates between data points: plot(real(rts(:,b)),imag(rts(:,b)),'.');